# submitchanges is not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

The variables are updating, but submitchanges not working. I think the problem is near my Users.dbml, but i don know what should i do! I think he do not communicate with my database, only with my Users.dbml.

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(GetConnectionString);

var a = (from p in db.Users
  where p.Username == tbloginName.Text
  select p).SingleOrDefault();
a.SessionId = Session.SessionID;

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: please check if types are same. Is there any thrown error for this?

Comment: The usual suspect: are you looking at the right database?

Comment: Do you have a PK in the table>